# how to re-install Kerberos client for ambari while wizard interrupt？

Tags: kerberos, ambari

The story was like this:

I wanted to enable the Kerberos service in ambari.I configured the server node kdc configuration but forgot to sync them to slave nodes. Then ran the wizard to enable kerberos, it got a failure after had already installed kerberos clients by the first step.

The error message shows that the client use admin@12 which realm is defalult by install kerberos server to client the kerberos server, while I configured the realm is EXAMPLE.COM. After I synced the configuration and re-ran the wizard, it has still shown the error.

I had tried every method to re-do. And also checked the operation in a new ambari environment.I guess the wrong realm is cached in the kerberos client. And every time re-run of the wizard, it skipped the install client step while it had been installed.

So, I come here to ask if there is a way to re-install the kerberos client.

Comment: Addition:maybe it's not a kerberos client wrong, but some client configuration cached in ambari-agent. I ```grep -rn @12``` at ```/var/lib/ambari-agent```, and got many json which is like temp configuration and txt which is like log message.

Answer (score 0):

The only option is to cleanup Kerberos completely and try enabling it again. Please use these set of cURL commands to clean up residual Kerberos configuration from Ambari (follow the sequence):

```
curl -H "X-Requested-By:ambari" -u admin:admin -i -X delete http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/bahubali/hosts/bali1.openstacklocal/host_components/KERBEROS_CLIENT

curl -H "X-Requested-By:ambari" -u admin:admin -i -X delete http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/bahubali/hosts/bali2.openstacklocal/host_components/KERBEROS_CLIENT

curl -H "X-Requested-By:ambari" -u admin:admin -i -X delete http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/bahubali/hosts/bali3.openstacklocal/host_components/KERBEROS_CLIENT

curl -H "X-Requested-By:ambari" -u admin:admin -i -X GET  http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/bahubali/services/KERBEROS/components/KERBEROS_CLIENT

curl -H "X-Requested-By:ambari" -u admin:admin -i -X DELETE  http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/bahubali/services/KERBEROS/components/KERBEROS_CLIENT

curl -H "X-Requested-By:ambari" -u admin:admin -i -X GET  http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/bahubali/services/KERBEROS

curl -H "X-Requested-By:ambari" -u admin:admin -i -X DELETE  http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/bahubali/services/KERBEROS
```

Comment: Thanks first. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: bahubali is the name of the cluster and bali[1-3].xxx are hostnames?

Comment: I got ```HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Connection: close``` return.

Comment: I use HDFS and NAMENODE to instead the KERBEROS and KERBEROS_CLIENT in the url to open url in the browers it's ok.While KERBEROS get ```"message" : "The requested resource doesn't exist: Service not found, clusterName=xxx, serviceName=KERBEROS"```